# Handle Data from SDK in Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to use the [MTG SDK](https://github.com/MagicTheGathering/mtg-sdk-javascript) to build a basic Card component. I am struggling to set the value of cardName variable to my output. How do I set my cardName data?

```
<template>
    <h1>{{ cardName }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
const mtg = require('mtgsdk')

export default {
    name: 'Card',
    data: function() {
        return {
            cardName: null //Set this value from method below
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getCardName()
        {
             mtg.card.find(3)
                .then(result => {
                this.cardName = result.card.name // "Black Lotus"
                });
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: You have to make your `cardName` a computed property or at least call `getCardName();` at some point in your application.

Comment: @CarlosF - Finally figured this out

cardName: mtg.card.find(3).then(result => { this.cardName = result.card.name  }),

Answer (score 0):

cardName: mtg.card.find(3).then(result => { this.cardName = result.card.name  })

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).